# Verify an input using Regular Expressions in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

A field that needs to be inputted must be in the exact form 6 numbers . four numbers

so for example 123456.0001

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) at MDN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below regex,

```
^[0-9]{6}\.[0-9]{4}$
```

You need to specify the start `^` and the end`$`.

**EXplanation:**

- `^` Means that we are at the beginning of the line.
- `[0-9]{6}` Matches a 6 digit number.
- `\.` Matches a literal dot.
- `[0-9]{4}` Matches a 4 digit number.
- `$` End of the line.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regular expression:

```
\d{6}\.\d{4}
```

For example:

```
/\d{6}\.\d{4}/.test("123456.1234");
=> true
/\d{6}\.\d{4}/.test("1234.123456");
=> false
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
if (/^\d{4}\.\d{6}$/m.test(yourString)) {
    // It matches!
} else {
    // Nah, no match...
}
```

**Explanation**

- The `^` anchor asserts that we are at the beginning of the string
- `\d{4}` matches four ASCII digits
- . matches a period
- `\d{6}` matches six ASCII digits
- The `$` anchor asserts that we are at the end of the string